# Train binary classifier with special online procedure instead of pre-defined train set

Tags: machine-learning, classification

My task is to build binary classification algorithm.
But training architecture is very specific.
There is no pre-defined train set,only special train interactive procedure,that is able to give true label only in case if algorithm 
predicts data point as positive.
One practical example: books critic has long list of books awaited for review-is this book good or bad.Some books are not nice for him for some unimportant reason(he doesn't like color of books cover),so he gives these books away and says,that rejected books are bad(but of course it will not be true label,and true label is unknown for them).As for other books he read them carefuly and gives complete opinion-true label-good or bad-for each of selected book.
This case is close to positive unlabeled classification,but not exactly that one.
So what classifier and how it should be trained,what loss function and eval metrics  should be used in train procedure?